# Fatal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException on Android 10 and above

Tags: android, sockets, websocket, okhttp, crashlytics

**I'm getting this crash on my app**

> (Platform.kt line 128
> okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket)
> Fatal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException failed to connect to
> domain/IP (port 443) from /Another IP (port 37062) after 120000ms:
> isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

**Crash details on firebase crashlytics**

```
libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected (IoBridge.java:343)


java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:646)
okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket (Platform.kt:128)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket (ConnectPlan.kt:246)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectTcp (ConnectPlan.kt:128)
okhttp3.internal.connection.SequentialExchangeFinder.find (SequentialExchangeFinder.kt:41)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp (RealCall.kt:267)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.kt:96)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:75)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
co.bosta.bosta_star_app.di.NetworkModuleKt$networkModule$1$invoke$provideOkHttpClient$$inlined$-addInterceptor$1.intercept (OkHttpClient.kt:1156)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept (HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:155)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp (RealCall.kt:205)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run (RealCall.kt:533)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)

java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
Caused by android.system.ErrnoException
isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected (IoBridge.java:334)

java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:646)
**okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket (Platform.kt:128)**
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectSocket (ConnectPlan.kt:246)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectPlan.connectTcp (ConnectPlan.kt:128)
okhttp3.internal.connection.SequentialExchangeFinder.find (SequentialExchangeFinder.kt:41)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp (RealCall.kt:267)
okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.kt:96)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:75)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
co.bosta.bosta_star_app.di.NetworkModuleKt$networkModule$1$invoke$provideOkHttpClient$$inlined$-addInterceptor$1.intercept (OkHttpClient.kt:1156)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept (HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:155)
okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp (RealCall.kt:205)
okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run (RealCall.kt:533)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)

java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
```

Also getting these crashes which also related to server connection

> Dns.kt line 49 okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup Fatal Exception:
> java.net.UnknownHostException Unable to resolve host "host.com": No
> address associated with hostname

> Http2Stream.kt line 675
> okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException
> Fatal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException timeout

> ConnectPlan.kt line 315 Fatal Exception:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException SSL handshake aborted:
> ssl=0x75dd3e3848: I/O error during system call, Software caused
> connection abort
>
> JvmOkio.kt line 94 okio.InputStreamSource.read Fatal Exception:
> java.net.SocketException Software caused connection abort

I found as some answers suggested I must add  this to my request but I still getting the crash after that

> ```
>         .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
>         .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
>         .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
> ```

Note: I check interent connection before making an API request using this method

```
  fun isConnected(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val networkInfo=connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
        if (capabilities != null &&  capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) && capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)) {
            when {
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> {
                    return true
                }
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> {
                    return true
                }
                capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Your app is running at points in time when the phone lacks a good Internet connection. That is not unusual.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated my question with the method I used to check internet connection before making any API request, however this internet check I getting these crashes?

Comment: All that does is indicate if there is a *possible* means of accessing the Internet. It does not indicate if Internet access actually works, let alone whether Internet access to your server (or whatever) actually works. Whether that access actually works varies over time, as users move around, switch between mobile data and WiFi, etc.

Comment: @Amin  is it only on android 10 and above

Comment: @Nadeem yes it is